# Is there way get separate part of a font in any graphic editing tool?

Tags: inkscape, svg, path

In this image as example for Letter R. I want to cut it into three pieces. Yellow color are cutting line.
After rectangle is portion, I want it in separately like this

Part 1:  |

Part 2:  D

Part 3:  \

Is there way to separate this into pieces?
InkScape or any other tools should be used for this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for Inskcape 1.0

1. Select and convert the R to outlines using *Path > Object to path*, then draw a path with the Bézier tool to act as the cut line. Then, using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>N</kbd>, select both paths. Note that holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click allows you to make a multiple selection.
2. Do *Path > Division* which is a boolean operation, then *Path > Break apart* to release the compound paths, then *Object > Ungroup*. The pieces will now be separate, and can be moved independently, or filled any colour, etc.

[image]

The same is possible in other vector image editors, such as Adobe Illustrator, since most vector software works on the same principles as Inkscape.  There are just different tools in different software. If I were using Illustrator, I'd probably use the Shape Builder tool, but the result would essentially be the same.

Comment: I understand but can you add GIF image explaining above?. I am newbie here.

Comment: GIF is a bitmap format traditionally used to make short animations (search Google, animated GIF). It's not particularly efficient or high quality, although it can output to a static image. When creating logos, letter forms and graphics that may be expanded to a large size or multiple production outputs, we use vector software such as Illustrator and formats such as EPS as these are more accurate and flexible. If you are simply making graphic pictures then Pixelmator might be a good start - similar tools and interface to Photoshop without the cost.

Comment: @Applefanoy can you please remove that comment. It's not relevant to the question or this answer, or the OPs comment.